# SVN / Git / Bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash, svn, git

I am working on a project with a team. They use SVN, but I prefer git. While I could do this more easily by simply getting better at SVN - I'd prefer to make my life complicated and use Git.

Here is their setup:

```
  ~/www(svn)
   |       \
trunk(svn)  mybranch(svn)
```

I would like to have

```
/srv/git/www
```

with branches trunk and mybranch

when I do git pull inside the `/srv/git/www` while on the trunk branch I would just love it if a script ran svn update on `~/www/trunk` and update the git branch with any svn commits (so that the git history and commit messages matches the svn and commit messages)

it would do the same behavior on `git pull` on the git mybranch branch

My workflow would then be

```
git checkout trunk
git pull
git checkout mybranch
git rebase trunk
```

do some work

(if trunk hasn't been updated since I pulled on it):

```
git commit 
git push
git checkout trunk
git merge mybranch
git push
```

I would love it if a git hook would then trigger svn commit whenever code is pushed to either of those branches.

Please offer any advice. I initially tried just using SVN - but am so frustrated by it locking, and having to re-checkout whenever a merge goes bad that I'm super annoyed with SVN.

If anyone has a better model for doing this, please tell me. Otherwise it would be outstanding if you could point me in the direction of how to do it with git! I know there is a git svn command, but I don't trust it - I was hoping the above is safer (albeit it seems a little insane to me.)

Thank you!

Comment: It's insane that they _want_ to use svn over git. But that's another story...

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but you are aware of `git-svn` right?  A tool that gives you the ability to access SVN from git?

Comment: @Zoredache Your comment is what I would've put in as the *answer* to this dilemma. Consider answering with that so this question might be set to answered status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've described how [SubGit](http://subgit.com/2.0/) works. Since 2.0 it allows a bi-directional translation between Git and SVN using pre-receive Git hook (that is executed on 'git push'). To do that run on your machine

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url <URL_of_repository_root> repo.git
$ #adjust repo.git/subgit/{config,passwd,authors.txt} to set auth options, branches to translate and SVN<->Git authors mapping
$ subgit install repo.git
```

Then clone repo.git (even if it's on the same machine just to make 'pre-receive' hook work)

```
$ git clone repo.git myproject
$ cd myproject
$ #do something with master
$ git push origin master
```

Every new commit reachable from 'master' will be translated to a commit in SVN. By default the same is true for other branches.

Answer (score 3):

> I initially tried just using SVN - but am so frustrated by it locking, and having to re-checkout whenever a merge goes bad that I'm super annoyed with SVN.

I really haven't noticed Subversion having the problems you seem to have. I don't experience it *locking* and merges with Subversion work pretty well. In fact, I have fewer issues with Subversion merges than Git merges. I suspect much of your frustration is working with unfamiliar software rather than innate problems with Subversion itself. I too get frustrated at software that doesn't work the way I'm use to.

However, you might as well get use to Subversion instead of going around the issue. You're going to run into Subversion over and over again because it is popular in the software world. It is simple to use and does a pretty good job. In this world, you might prefer OS X and Linux to Windows, but you still need to know Windows. I know I get frustrated at unfamiliar software too. However, unlike Windows, Subversion isn't evil. Besides, it does works pretty well.

One thing I do like about Git which I sorely miss with Subversion is the ability to commit my work without it affecting the master repository. My workflow in Git looks like this:

```
git checkout
git pull
git add
git commit
git add
git commit
git add
git commit
git add
git commit
git add
git commit
git add
git commit
git push
```

If you're a serial committer like me, you might want to try [Git-SVN](http://viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion): This allows you to work with Git locally and do serial commits, but when you do pushes and pulls, you're really talking to the Subversion repository. However, this doesn't mean you can simply pretend you are working solely with Git. When I branch and merge, I still must talk directly with Subversion.

If you're not a serial committer, Git-SVN probably won't buy you much. All you end up doing is adding complexity and more frustration.

Subversion is designed to work on the *unstable trunk* model which is used in continuous integration environments. That means everyone usually shares the same branch. It forces you to play nicely with others and to make small incremental changes. However, there's no reason why you can't make your own private branch in Subversion and do your work there.

I do a lot of code restructuring and that means moving files around and doing a lot of work that can't be done in a single day. I can't work on the same branch all the other developers are using, so I make my own private branch. If anyone should have merging issues, it would be me because I'm not merely modifying a file here or there, I'm changing the whole layout of the code. Yet, Subversion almost always handles the merging with aplomb. I rebase on a regular basis. When I finish my work, I'll do a massive delivery without any problems. Then, I'll delete my branch.